# Index of the condition that was satisfied inside if-statement

Tags: c++, c

```
    if(command[i]=='H' or command[i]=='h' or command[i]=='C' or command[i]=='c'){
        do something;
    }
```

Once the logic flow goes inside this if-statement, I want to know what exactly command[i] was. Surely I can make individual comparisons again in the inside block and find out, but is there a more elegant way of knowing, say, the index of the condition that was satisfied?

Comment: Is there a macro involved? Your expression looks neither C nor C++.

Comment: Even assuming that by `or` you mean `||`, this if statement will always evaluate to true with at least 3 conditions being true.

Comment: Try `if((myC=command[i]) =='H' or (myC=command[i])=='h' or (myC=command[i]) =='C' or (myC=command[i])=='c')` and look at `myC` afterwards.

Comment: Sorry I messed up in writing the code. Fixed it

Comment: @Tibrogargan, || can be replaced with 'or' isn't it? Both g++ and clang interpret it properly

Comment: You have tagged neither of those.

Comment: @Yunnhosch Thank you, that can work

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative#Alternative_tokens - this is legal C and C++

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens @Tibrogargan

Comment: @Amav you could just use `switch` for this.

Comment: *I  want to know what exactly command[i] was* It isn't quite clear what you mean by that. The value of `command[i]` was and is `command[i]`. Please show your inelegant code, otherwise it's rather impossible to know what you are trying to make elegant.

Comment: Ah I just realized my redundancy. So the reason I was looking for index of satisfied condition was for this-

if (command[i]='h')
do stuff1;
if(command[i]='H' or command[i]='h')
do stuff 2;

Instead of writing that, I can just make a switch statement if I have a number for the condition satisfied

Comment: I realized I can use switch with chars too, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
if((myC=command[i]) =='H' ||
   (myC=command[i]) =='h' ||
   (myC=command[i]) =='C' ||
   (myC=command[i]) =='c')
```

then the value of the successful expression will end up in `myC`, because evaluation in a chain of "or"s stops at the first true subexpression.

If you go one step further you can get a number value identifying the subexpression by index.

```
if(((myC=1), command[i]) =='H' ||
   ((myC=2), command[i]) =='h' ||
   ((myC=3), command[i]) =='C' ||
   ((myC=4), command[i]) =='c')
```

Same concept, the first successful subexpüression is the last to be evaluated and the `,` operator ensures that only the second part gets used for the comparison.

Comment: why use variable "myC" to store some value which is already present in another variable "command[i]". You can just check the value of "command[i]" and you will know which if-condition was satisfied.

Comment: This one is better. :)

Comment: Needed a fix though... ;-)

Comment: How is this different to just using the value of `command[i]`?  You will end up comparing myC to a value that could be stored in a char anyway.  You may as well be doing `if ((myC='H'), command[i]) == 'H' || ...`

Comment: @Tibrogargan It is better because it answers the exact question by OP. "Index of ...".

Comment: Thank you! it is a valid solution. However, I  realized that since it's a single char comparison, I can just use switch statements

Comment: Technically, it answers the literal question that was asked.  It is not however, "better"

Comment: It is better than my first version answer, because it answers the question and because it does not only store something which is also available in `command[i]`. That was a valid input in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to assign a value. You could use `switch`, an `if..else` tower, or a function with `return` statements. Here is a version with function:

```
int classify( char command )
{
    switch( command )
    {
    case 'H': return 1;
    case 'h': return 2;
    case 'C': return 3;
    case 'c': return 4;
    default : return 0;
    }
}

void func(void)
{
    int result = classify( command[i] );
    if ( result )
    {
         // use result value here as appropriate
    }
}
```

It would also be possible, in fact preferable, to use an enumerator instead of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this -

```
if(command[i]=='H' or command[i]=='h' or command[i]=='C' or command[i]=='c'){
        print command[i]; //use whatever command is appropriate for printing
        do something;
    }
```